# What information does Baseband Provides in Android?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I know that the baseband is the subsystem of the phone that controls radio communications. It's a chipset on the phone that directly controls cellular hardware and communications with cell towers. I also know that on older devices may control wifi, bluetooth, and GPS. The question is here that what kind of information can it provide that I can use in my android application?  Just the signal strength or anymore? I also has connection with `Android Telephony Manager`, what about the Telephony info?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Really a great question, I wish you receive proper answers

Comment: I have same problem, any answer???

Answer (score 1):

Baseband processor is connected to application processor via a serial connection UART . Connection established through RIL (Radio Interface Layer) . RIL has implemenation both in native user space and in framework . Telephony manager connects to RIL.java in framework and communication is made . You can access Telephony manager through this code :

```
Telephonymanager tm = (Telephonymanager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE)
```

Then you can access a variety informations about phone state like cell infos , calling state , neighbor cells , signal stength , IMSI , IMEI and etc .

In order to access to cell tower infos , you can use this :

```
tm.getAllCellInfo()
```

It returns a list of CellInfo and you can iterate over it to access information about each cell .